# Java, inside a method, cannot convert double to string

Tags: java, string, methods, double

I'm very new to Java, so I apologize if this is a simple error. I have a java class that is given a double and has to use a method to return it as a string. I get varying results.

I've tried incorporating a string converter in the get Method. I've tried to use an additional method, specifically for conversion handling. 
I've tried `Double.parsedouble()`, `valueOf()`, `toString()`. Generally, these work in the main class, but my assignment specifies it must be in a method.

//Several other methods, and default constructor omitted.

```
public class GuitarFubar {
    private double guitarLength;

    }

    public GuitarFubar(double guitarLength){
        this.guitarLength = guitarLength;
    }

    public double getGuitarLen(double guitarLength){
        return guitarLength;
    }


    // also tried its own method.. it will only return 0.0..

    public String sillyString(){
        String str0 = "" + guitarLength;
        return str0;
    }
}
```

-------Main Class -----

```
public class GuitarMClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        GuitarFubar output2 = new GuitarFubar();
        String mkShft2 = ("" + output2.getGuitarLen(12.2)); 

        GuitarFubar bString = new GuitarFubar();
        System.out.println(bString.sillyString());

   }
}
```

Actual Results
"Error: Cannot convert double to string" or 
the print is 0.0 (when it should be 12.2))

Comment: Your code will not compile as written. Please create a minimal program that demonstrates your issue. (And please indicate what that issue is; it's bizarre to write "Actual Results 'Error: Cannot convert double to string' or the print is 0.0 (when it should be 12.2))", as if the same code sometimes did one and sometimes the other.)

Comment: Sure, I didn't want to throw it all in, but here it is in full. I'd REALLY appreciate the help with this.

Comment: The actual conversion `"" + guitarLength` does work (although calling `String.valueOf(guitarLength)` is probably better). Your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Your code is missing a no argument constructor and there is no setter for setting the guitar length. Your getter method is just parroting back the guitar length that is passed in.

Comment: In your main method only thing you print is `System.out.println(bString.sillyString());` but `GuitarFubar bString = new GuitarFubar();` creates `GuitarFubar` using no-argument constructor which you are not showing us. BUT based on what is actually printed it most likely looks like `public GuitarFubar(){ }` or `public GuitarFubar(){ guitarLength = 0.0; }` so it holds `0.0` as value for `guitarLength `. I am not sure what makes you think that it should print other result like 12.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Java class [`Double`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString-double-) contains a static method that will do what you're looking for.

```java
Double.toString(doubleValue)
```

You could fix your problem in a couple of different ways, depending on the functionality you want your `GuitarFubar` class to have:

```java
public class GuitarMClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // OPTION 1
        GuitarFubar output2 = new GuitarFubar();
        output2.setGuitarLength(12.2);
        String mkShft2 = output2.getGuitarLengthAsString();
        System.out.println(mkShft2);

        // OPTION 2
        GuitarFubar bString = new GuitarFubar();
        bString.setGuitarLength(12.2);  //your example code never sets the value of guitarLength, which is why one of your outputs is '0.0'
        System.out.println(Double.toString(bString.getGuitarLength()));

        // OPTION 3
        GuitarFubar guitarFubar = new GuitarFubar(12.2); // actually use the guitar length when constructing a new instance
        System.out.println(Double.toString(guitarFubar.getGuitarLength()));
   }

   public class GuitarFubar {
        private double guitarLength;

        // make sure you have a no-args constructor if that's how you are going to instantiate your class
        public GuitarFubar(){
        }

        public GuitarFubar(double guitarLength){
            this.guitarLength = guitarLength;
        }

        // make sure you have a proper 'getter'
        public double getGuitarLength(){
            return this.guitarLength;
        }

        // make sure you have a proper 'setter'
        public void setGuitarLength(double guitarLength){
            this.guitarLength = guitarLength;
        }

        // alternative to sillyString method if you want this functionality within your GuitarFubar class 
        // (although not required since a caller of getGuitarLength() can handle String conversion)
        public String getGuitarLengthAsString() {
            return Double.toString(this.guitarLength);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your method

```
public String sillyString(){
    String str0 = "" + guitarLength;
    return str0;
}
```

to:

```
public String sillyString(double doubleToString){
    return  "" + doubleToString;
}
```

And call it from main like :

```
System.out.println(bString.sillyString(213.3d));
```

Comment: There is no need to box the double into a `Double`

Answer (score 0):

here's the root of your confusion:

```
public double getGuitarLen(double guitarLength){
    return guitarLength;
}
```

That's not a getter. It's not a setter either. That's a shunt that just gives back exactly what it got without storing the value anywhere.

```
GuitarFubar output2 = new GuitarFubar();
```

This won't compile because your constructor demands an argument. Even if you give it one `getGuitarLen` won't return it because it's still a shunt. If you change `getGuitarLen` to

```
public double getGuitarLen(){
    return this.guitarLength;
}
```

it still wont work because you never declared

```
double guitarLength;
```

as part of `GuitarFubar` state.

Make those changes and it should work.

Not that you really need to do any of that because the expression:

```
"" + doubleToString;
```

will be turned into a string. Doesn't matter if you're inside a method. It does matter if `doubleToString` has been declared and given a value. Any way you do that, methods, constructors, or initializers, will get this working.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to keep it simple:

We have a class with one field

```
public class GuitarFubar {
    private double length;

    // next code snippets go here!
}
```

two options to set (initial) length: constructor and method (setter):

```
public GuitarFubar(double length) {
    this.length = length;
}

public void setLength(double length) {
    this.length = length;
}
```

and one method to get the length:

```
public double getLength() {
    return this.length;
}
```

finally the method to get its length as String:

```
public String getLengthAsString() {
    return Double.toString(this.length);
}
```

but the problem isn't solved - the length need to be set, default value is zero. In calling (main) method

```
GuitarFubar guitar = new GuitarFubar(12.2);
System.out.println(guitar.getLengthAsString());
```

or, using setter if no constructor is was implemented:

```
GuitarFubar guitar = new GuitarFubar();
guitar.setLength(12.2);
System.out.println(guitar.getLengthAsString());
```

---

If we want the length to be immutable, we declare it as `final` (must not be changed), have it set in the constructor and do not implement a setter:

```
public class GuitarFubar {
    private final double length;

    public GuitarFubar(double length) {
        this.length = length;
    }

    public double getLength() {
        return this.length;
    }

    public String getLengthAsString() {
        return Double.toString(this.length);
    }
}
```

must be created like `new GuitarFubar(12.2);`